# Postgresql Range lower bound must be less than or equal to range upper bound

Tags: sql, postgresql, range

I have a query that checks for schedule time overlaps for schools in a Postgres database. The issue is, the query below throws this error
`ERROR:  range lower bound must be less than or equal to range upper bound SQL state: 22000`  in certain schools but works in others. Any help will be appreciated.

```
SELECT ls.* 
FROM lesson_schedules ls 
WHERE TSRANGE( CAST(CONCAT(ls.start_date, ' ', ls.start_time) AS TIMESTAMP) , CAST(CONCAT(ls.end_date, ' ', ls.end_time) AS TIMESTAMP), '()') 
      && TSRANGE( CAST(CONCAT('2021-01-15', ' ','09:00:00+00') AS TIMESTAMP), CAST(CONCAT('2021-01-15', ' ','09:40:00+00') AS TIMESTAMP), '()') 
AND ls.school_id = 6 
AND ls.grade_id = 58 
AND ls.parent = FALSE
```

Comment: Please show us a sample of your data. It seems that your start is greater than your end.

Comment: Unrelated, but: if `start_date` is a `date` and `start_time` is a `time` then `CAST(CONCAT(ls.start_date, ' ', ls.start_time) AS TIMESTAMP` can be simplified to `ls.start_date + ls.start_time` - but the real question is why that isn't a single column defined as `timestamp`  - and  `CAST(CONCAT('2021-01-15', ' ','09:00:00+00') AS TIMESTAMP` can be simplified to `timestamp '2021-01-15 '09:00:00'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the error message is self-explanatory: you have rows where `start_date + start_time` is bigger than `end_date + end_time`.

To find those rows you can use:

```
select *
from lesson_schedules
where start_date + start_time > end_date + end_time;
```

(The above assumes that `start_date` and `end_date` are `date` columns and that `start_time` and `end_time` are `time` columns)

Once you have those rows, fix their dates.

---

One way to prevent such "corrupted" data in the future is to create a check constraint (using the above expression) or create a single `tsrange` column.

Comment: you are right. I just checked and in fact, there are a couple of rows with start_date greater than the end date.